# Getting control of other window

Tags: mfc

I have a project in MFC which is integrated with a billing application.We have two seperate MFC window:
1)One for Billing App. and other for
2)the project.

Initially we log in with the project window.then we start transaction with the project window.after transaction we need to click a button on Billing Application,but the focus is still on the project window.How can we set the focus/KeyPressEvent to the Billing App?

Thanks,
ksh

Comment: does both the windows belong to the same application

Comment: Jeeva, asked that because to communication to target window becomes easy

Answer (score 0):

[FindWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  to get hWnd of Billing App.

[PostMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to simulate key events.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `FindWindow()` to get the other window.
- `EnumChildWindows()` function to get the Child controls of other Window. Then you can get handle of all the controls. Then do SetFocus.